# Nested GROUP SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table MYTABLE.
This contains customers and locations.

What Sql statement can I use to find out what customers have more than 1 location
and only display on those with more than 1 location? A location can be used for several different customers.

This  did not work: this only showed the number of Occurances

```
SELECT CU _NO, LOC_NO, COUNT(LOC_NO) AS NUMBEROCC
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY LOC_NO
HAVING (COUNT(LOC_NO)>1)
```

The table has more than one row of of the same customer(sorry this was important)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT m.CU_NO
     , m.LOC_NO
     , grp.NUMBEROCC
FROM MYTABLE AS m
  JOIN
    ( SELECT CU_NO
           , COUNT(DISTINCT LOC_NO) AS NUMBEROCC
      FROM MYTABLE
      GROUP BY CU_NO
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT LOC_NO) > 1
    ) AS grp
    ON grp.CU_NO = m.CU_NO
ORDER BY m.CU_NO
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to include all non-aggregated fields of your `SELECT` clause in the `GROUP BY` clause, so you have to remove the `LOC` field and group by `CU_NO`.

```
SELECT CU_NO, COUNT(LOC_NO) AS NUMBEROCC
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY CU_NO
HAVING (COUNT(LOC_NO)>1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a window function if you want to get all the locations of all the customers with more than one location:

```
SELECT t.CU_NO, t.LOC_NO, t.NUMBEROCC
FROM (
    SELECT CU_NO, LOC_NO, COUNT(LOC_NO) OVER (PARTITION BY CU_NO) AS NUMBEROCC
    FROM MYTABLE
) AS t
WHERE t.NUMBEROCC > 1
```

If you don't care about all the locations, but just the customer ids, then you can use simple group by clause:

```
SELECT CU_NO
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY CU_NO
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT LOC_NO) > 1
```

But in both cases you want to group by CU_NO, not by LOC_NO!

---

SQL-Server implementation of window functions has not (yet!) included `COUNT(DISTINCT x) OVER(PARTITION BY x)`. So, this raises error:

```
SELECT t.CU_NO, t.LOC_NO, t.NUMBEROCC
FROM (
    SELECT CU_NO, LOC_NO
         , COUNT(DISTINCT LOC_NO) OVER (PARTITION BY CU_NO) AS NUMBEROCC
    FROM MYTABLE
) AS t
WHERE t.NUMBEROCC > 1
```

Workaround is to use `DENSE_RANK() OVER()` and `MAX() OVER()` with one additional query level:

```
SELECT x.CU_NO, x.LOC_NO, x.NUMBEROCC
FROM (
    SELECT t.CU_NO, t.LOC_NO
         , MAX(DR) OVER(PARTITION BY CU_NO) AS NUMBEROCC
    FROM (
        SELECT CU_NO, LOC_NO
             , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CU_NO ORDER BY LOC_NO) AS DR
        FROM MYTABLE
    ) AS t
) AS x
WHERE x.NUMBEROCC > 1
```

Comment: The problem your first statement shows the CU_NO_ LOC_NO followed by the total number of all customers with that location. the second shows customers that only have one location. Its my fault as the table contains the same customer more than once.( I Simplified but this has caused confusion)

Comment: are you sure... that can't be. It's ok to have the same customer more than once, if he has more than one location.

Comment: I have modified the aggregate to be `COUNT(DISTINCT LOC_NO)`. This way even you have duplicate row (same custome with same location twice) it will be correct

Comment: The Distinct works fantastic for statement 2 but statement 1 causes error Incorrect syntax near 'distinct'.

Comment: ah, maybe this is not a valid window function :(

Comment: @icecurtain: It's a limitation of SQL-Server window functions implementation: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/254393/over-clause-enhancement-request-distinct-clause-for-aggregate-functions